# Where does "dpkg -l "*"" gather its information?

Tags: debian, dpkg

As I understand, `dpkg -l "*"` under Debian lists all the available packages regardless of their state. Where does this information come from? I understand that `/var/lib/dpkg/available` lists all the installed packages(state `ii`), but where does the `dpkg` get information about all the other packages?

Comment: I think your information is incorrect. `dpkg -l "*"` does not list all available packages.

Comment: `/var/lib/aptitude/pkgstats`

Comment: @MohsenPahlevanzadeh No, because dpkg has nothing to do with aptitude. dpkg works fine without aptitude installed.

Comment: @FaheemMitha You are probably correct. However, which packages `dpkg -l "*"` lists? Even in case of pretty much fresh installation, it lists ~1000 packages with desired status "unknown" and actual status "not installed".

Comment: As of right now, I don't know the answer to your question. However, if I figure it out, I'll add an answer. Also, I think @wurtel has answered your question about what file it is getting the information from, but perhaps the more interesting question is what that list represents. You ask the former question, but not the latter.

Answer (score 5):

The way I check such things is by running the utility under control of `strace`, e.g.:

```
$ strace -o /tmp/dpkg-strace.out dpkg -l '*'
```

`strace` traces all usage of system calls, so it's easy to see what files are accessed. grep the output file for `open` system calls, and with some experience you can quickly see that in this case the relevant strace line is:

```
open("/var/lib/dpkg/status", O_RDONLY)  = 3
```

Hence `/var/lib/dpkg/status` is the file `dpkg` gets its info from. It's basically a plain text file (formatted somewhat according to RFC2822) so you can look at it with `less` or similar.

Comment: I think poster need to knows every package without `ii` such as `up` . When you `grep ^Status: /var/lib/dpkg/status` You only get `install ok installed` and it means `ii`

Comment: I tried the same on RedHat distros using `strace -o /tmp/rpm-strace.out rpm -qa` but I can not find and equivalent to `/var/lib/dpkg/status` file. Any hints??

Comment: AFAICS from strace output on RPM systems is that it uses non-text files in /var/lib/rpm/ .  It looks like these are Berkeley DB files.